# DuckDB: How to connect to the remote host file using DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver, duckdb

I have a file A on a remote host with address IP. How can I connect to this using the DBeaver client?

what is confusing me, there is no user/password needed for DuckDB, at least I didn't find in the docs, where and how to configure this.. I just have user/password for my remote host.

[image: DBeaver - DuckDB configuration dialog]

Answer (score 0):

DuckDB doesn't natively support a setup like this, but you can use something like https://github.com/jwills/buenavista as a proxy